# A confusion about the source code for ConcurrentHashMap's putVal method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

Here is part of codes for `putVal` method:

```
final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
    if (key == null || value == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    int hash = spread(key.hashCode());
    int binCount = 0;
    for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {
        Node<K,V> f; int n, i, fh;
        if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
            tab = initTable();  // lazy Initialization
        //step1,tabAt(...) is CAS
        else if ((f = tabAt(tab, i = (n - 1) & hash)) == null) {
            //step2,casTabAt(...) is CAS
            if (casTabAt(tab, i, null,
                         new Node<K,V>(hash, key, value, null)))
                break;                   // no lock when adding to empty bin
        }
       ...
    return null;
}
```

Suppose there are currently two threads, `A` and `B`, and when `A` executes the `step1` , it gets `true` ,but at the same time `B` also executes `step1` and gets `true` as well. And both `A` and `B` execute `step2`.

[image]

from this situation, `B`'s `Node` replace the `A`'s `Node`, or said `A`'s data is replaced by `B`, this's is wrong.

I don't know is it right or wrong, can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the full source code?

Comment: Here is the [source code](https://github.com/mynawang/Java8-Source-Code/blob/master/src/main/jdk8/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how `casTabAt` is implemented:

```
static final <K,V> boolean casTabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i,
                                    Node<K,V> c, Node<K,V> v) {
    return U.compareAndSwapObject(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE, c, v);
}
```

Whereas `U` is declared as follows: `private static final sun.misc.Unsafe U;`. Methods of this class **guarantees atomicity** at low level. And from this usage:

```
casTabAt(tab, i, null, new Node<K,V>(hash, key, value, null))
```

we can see, [assuming that the third parameter of `compareAndSwapObject` is expected value, that](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-sunmiscunsafe), due to atomicity guaranteed, either `A` or `B` thread **that executes `compareAndSwapObject` first** will see `null` here and `compareAndSwapObject` **will actually replace the object**, whereas the next thread executing `compareAndSwapObject` won't change the value, because **the actual value is not null anymore, whereas null was expected as a condition to make a change for a value**.

Comment: yeah,I know that,so It means on that case,Thread B will not put the value in the ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Actually no: `compareAndSwapObject`, as well as `catTabAt` returns true if replacement was performed. And given that `if (casTabAt(tab, i, null, new Node<K,V>(hash, key, value, null))) break; ` won't call `break` (because for the second write operation it will return `false`) - the top-level cycle (`for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {...}`) will just run one more time.

Comment: You are always welcome :)
If I helped you - please, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.